# How to list the databases/models under Azure Analysis Services using Powershell?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-analysis-services

I have a task that I need to automate. The task involves getting the list of Databases/Models present in the Azure Analysis Services model using Powershell Script

I have written the following Powershell script

```
$serverName = "ServerName"
$ResourceGroupName = "ResourceGroupName"

$server = Get-AzAnalysisServicesServer -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $serverName
 
$ServerName = $server.ServerFullName
```

Currently using the Get-AzAnalysisServicesServer doesn't return the models/database under it and I did not find any other command that could help me list the databases.

After doing some research I came across an article that suggested using Microsoft.AnalysisServices assembly.

```
# Load the Microsoft.AnalysisServices assembly
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices")

# Connect to the Azure Analysis Services server
$MyServer = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server

$MyServer.Connect($ServerName)

# Check if the server connection is successful
if ($MyServer.Connected) {
    Write-Output "Connected to Azure Analysis Services server: $ServerName"

    # Get the list of databases from the server
    $Databases = $MyServer.Databases

    # Check if there are databases present
    if ($Databases.Count -gt 0) {
        Write-Output "List of databases:"
        foreach ($Database in $Databases) {
            Write-Output $Database.Name
        }
    } else {
        Write-Output "No databases found on the server."
    }
} else {
    Write-Output "Failed to connect to Azure Analysis Services server: $ServerName"
}

# Close the connection to the server
$MyServer.Disconnect()
Write-Output "Connection to Azure Analysis Services server closed."
```

Using the above script fails at the `$MyServer.Connect($ServerName)` with the following error:
`AADSTS50011: The redirect URI 'some url' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application '<application_id>'. Make sure the redirect URI sent in the request matches one added to your application in the Azure portal.`

Is there any other way to get the list of databases or this is not possible at all? Also, how can I fix the redirect URI issue as the application id mentioned in the error is not present in our Azure subscription.

Image for Error :

[image]